# Remembering original destination after authentication with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

If a user accesses a protected page but is not signed in, I'd like to do the following -

1. Redirect them to a "Log In" page with the original destination saved as a query parameter. e.g. `/log-in?dest=%2Faccount%2Fsettings`
2. On successful log in, redirect to the originally intended page instead of the default `root_path`, in this case `/account/settings`

Is there an easy way to accomplish this using Devise? By default it doesn't seem to "remember" the original page after logging in so I'm guessing I'll have to override some `before_action` somewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the devise gem has an awesome wiki where a lot of questions are answered in a tutorial style way.
So for your second question, you can follow. this one:

- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update

One tip for this one: in the "first approach" they mention that

> To redirect to the stored location after the user signs in you would override the after_sign_in_path_for method:

You can define this method in the devise controllers if you generate them.

Following this approcach you probably don't even need your first point.